# How to trigger a model update from $resource.save()?

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently trying to build my first angular app, and I could need a little help.

I'm accessing a REST service with the standard $resource actions:

```
angular.module('wtrack', ['ngResource']).
    factory('WtrackAPI', function($resource) {
      var WtrackAPI = $resource('http://hostname/wtrack/api/w/:id');
      return WtrackAPI;
    });
```

And this is my controller:

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $timeout, WtrackAPI){

    $scope.wdata = WtrackAPI.query(); // a list of objects displayed in my view

    $scope.addEntry = function() {   // adding an object to the list
        console.log("Adding Entry");
        var entry = {day: $scope.wdata.day, value: $scope.wdata.value};
        WtrackAPI.save(entry, 
                          function(){console.log("WTF do I need to do here to rerun WtrackAPI.query()");});
    };

}
```

What I'd want to do is basically update my model by executing `$scope.wdata = WtrackAPI.query();` again once the save() is done. I suspect the angular way would be to just `$scope.wdata.push(entry)`, but in this case the database adds some data to the entry with triggers and does some complex sorting, so I really want to roundtrip and reload the whole list using query. How can I make this happen? Just calling `$scope.wdata = WtrackAPI.query();` in the save callback doesn't work as $scope apparently doesn't exist in there. I tried a few other things with $emit and $rootScope etc, but all that did was making me really confused. So please, can anybody give me a hint on what's the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$scope` object should be accessible in the closure scope so you should be able to write:

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $timeout, WtrackAPI){

    $scope.wdata = WtrackAPI.query(); // a list of objects displayed in my view

    $scope.addEntry = function() {   // adding an object to the list

        var entry = {day: $scope.wdata.day, value: $scope.wdata.value};
        WtrackAPI.save(entry, function() {
           //$scope should be accessible here
           $scope.wdata = WtrackAPI.query();
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Yeah now it works, I must have messed up something else somewhere else, sorry for the noise & thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer will give you a flash of a blank model momentarily.  I recommend this for a cleaner model update:

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $timeout, WtrackAPI){
        $scope.queryWData = function() {
            WtrackAPI.query(function(response){
                // set the wdata here, in the callback
                $scope.wdata = response;
            })
        };
        $scope.addEntry = function() {   // adding an object to the list
            console.log("Adding Entry");
            var entry = {day: $scope.wdata.day, value: $scope.wdata.value};
            WtrackAPI.save(entry,
                function(){
                    $scope.queryWData();
                });
        };
        $scope.queryWData();
    }
```

I would recommend against setting `$scope.wdata` equal to the `$resource` outright, because, before that resource responds, you will have $scope.wdata be blank.  This will cause a significant flash of blank content before your model actually updates.

To rectify this, we set the `$scope.wdata` in the `$resource` callback

Comment: a second request seems overkill. At least in my rest API, the updated (and possibly changed by server) object is included in the PUT/POST response.